# Make panes resize when host window is resized

Tags: split, vimdiff

I like to use vimdiff as a git diff/merge tool. The problem is when I resize the host terminal window to a new size: of the two split panes, the leftmost remain of the same width, while the rightmost is extended to full window size.

Is there a command to make the split panes equal width after the windows has been resized? Or a setting that makes the panes always be of same size? I looked into `:set equalalways` but it does not seem to do what I am asking.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To go along with @janos's answer, you can set an `autocmd` to automatically press those keys when the window is resized (put this in your `.vimrc` without the leading colon if you want it to apply every time you open Vim):

```
:autocmd VimResized * wincmd =
```

[Here are the docs for the `VimResized` autocmd](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#VimResized).

Comment: i couldn't make it work with `<C-v> <C-w>`; I used `autocmd VimResized * wincmd =` in my .vimrc instead

Comment: I had the same problem as guido did with `^W` and `<C-w>` not working. If you don't mind, I edited your answer to show the other method. Feel free to review this change, or rollback if you disagree.

Answer (score 17):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> will resize the split panes to become equal. But I don't know how to make them equal automatically, triggered when the window is resized.