# Tabbing between files

Tags: key-bindings

I am trying to add the following lines to my `.vimrc`

```
nnoremap <C-Tab> <C-w>w
nnoremap <C-S-Tab> <C-w>W
```

As per [Vim Tutorial](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Switching_between_files)

However I can't seem to get these to work. Other mappings I have tried work well. I am running Linux Mint 18. Any ideas of what I am doing wrong. I am a long time VI user - although have always just used standard setup no major customisation.

Answer (score 3):

This is because `<C-w>` in vimscript and mappings is very buggy. For whatever reason, I frequently find cases where it doesn't work [such as this one](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/206/2920).

But thankfully, the solution is simple. You can do `wincmd w` or `wincmd W` as an ex command instead.

```
nnoremap <C-tab> :wincmd w<cr>
nnoremap <C-S-tab> :wincmd W<cr>
```

Works just fine for me.