# How do I execute normal commands from an autocmd?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

I am trying to do some window management in VIM where I create certain windows such as two or three vertical splits with different sizes.

At the moment, I only know how to change panes with `<C-w>h/j/k/l`

How am I meant to tell my `~/.vimrc` to automatically go to the pane to the right?

I have tried `autocmd VimEnter * <C-w>l` but that does not do anything.

Comment: iProgram, I suggested the edit to the title because the body of your question has to do with window commands and vimscript (ex commands), not “executing keybindings” (which, tbh, doesnt make a lot of sense). I was hoping to bring them together so that title and body align.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I see what you mean. Its just because I was while doing window management, it just so happens to use keybindings. By asking this question, it makes it more generic. For example, whenever you want to simulate `<C-w>`, you can do it via `wincmd`. If you still think it's a good idea to edit the title, feel free and I will accept.

Comment: What about “How do I execute normal commands from an autocmd?”

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Sorry about that. It's because I thought normal mode commands were different from pressing keybindings in normal mode. That could work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to run commands as if you had typed keys automatically when you start vim, you'll need to use the `normal` command (to run a *normal mode* command).

```
:norm[al][!] {commands}                 *:norm* *:normal*
            Execute Normal mode commands {commands}.  This makes
            it possible to execute Normal mode commands typed on
            the command-line.  {commands} are executed like they
            are typed.  For undo all commands are undone together.
            Execution stops when an error is encountered.
```

So you'd need `autocmd VimEnter * normal <C-w>l`. **However**, vim is really dumb about the `<C-w>` family of commands. [For example this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/14457/tabbing-between-files/14458#14458) of mine. I still don't know why this happens, I just know it's a quirk of vimscript.

Thankfully, there's an easy way around this:

```
:[count]winc[md] {arg}
        Like executing CTRL-W [count] {arg}.  Example: >
            :wincmd j
<       Moves to the window below the current one.
        This command is useful when a Normal mode cannot be used (for
        the |CursorHold| autocommand event).  Or when a Normal mode
        command is inconvenient.
        The count can also be a window number.  Example: >
            :exe nr . "wincmd w"
<       This goes to window "nr".
```

So you should be able to do what you want with `autocmd VimEnter * wincmd l`. Although this might not do very much, since typically there would only be one split open when you open up vim for the first time.

Comment: Thanks for that. Its because I have NERDTree open automatically on startup. I am then using a.out for when I edit .cpp files to create a vertical split and open the header file. Thats why I want it.

Comment: @iProgram Ah, that makes sense. Glad I could help! :)